# Porting POSIX functions to freertos

Tags: pthreads, posix, freertos, condition-variable

How can I use a `pthread_cond_wait()` in freertos? In my code there is section which waits for a signal from `pthread_cond_signal()`. This is a function which unblocks the condition thread. So I need to port these two functions..any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Condition in FreeRTOS but there are [Event groups](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Event-Groups.html), [Message queues](https://www.freertos.org/a00018.html) and [Queue sets](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-queue-sets.html)

The perfect one to use depends on your specific needs (which were not disclosed in the question).

Look also on this post on the subject:

- https://www.freertos.org/Pend-on-multiple-rtos-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the simplest way to use simple **binary semaphore** and xSemaphoreGive()/xSemaphoreTake() functions from FreeRTOS.

Hope this will help you.